# How do I display list of contributors of my shared CKRecord?

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I already shared my record with another user or other user shared a record with me. Now I would like to present following controllers:

[image]
[image]

because this code:

```
            if let record = record {

                if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                    let share = CKShare(rootRecord: record)
                    let controller = UICloudSharingController(share: share, container: CloudAssistant.shared.container)
                    self.present(controller, animated: true)
                }
            }
```

Will present:

[image]

How can I achieve it?

Comment: It seems that that CKRecord is not being shared. Is it correct? Have you try to share it?

Comment: Yes, it is shared... for 100%. CKRecord appears in shared database when I get in cloudkit dashboard of related account.

Comment: Is it possible at all to present such controller? How would you do that?

Comment: But it may be that CKShare is wrong. What do you think? Should I do it like this?

Comment: Did you add participants to the CKShare?

Comment: I did it like this: created ckrecord and share it with sending link to other user. The other user did tap the link, retrieved the record and... voilla. I think that way participants should be added automatically...

Comment: Could you fetch that record and check the participants property? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckshare/1640453-participants

Comment: Should I fetch that CKShare record? Is not enough that I create it base on shared CKRecord?

Comment: No, Fetch operation it's only to vertify that CKRecord has participants. That's why I asked you to check that property :-)

Comment: You were right:) I fetched CKShare and it worked properly:) Controller appeared:)